# Spring : combine 2 entities into model object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a requirement to combine 2 entity objects into 1 model object that will be used to return data back to a calling api method. Is there a common pattern or solution for this scenario?

```
@Entity
public class Entity1{
   @Column
   private String value1;
   @Column
   private String value2;
}

@Entity    
public class Entity2{
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "value1")
   private Entity1 entity1;

   @Column
   private String value3;
}
```

Comment: Is it a one-to-one relation?

Comment: Not familiar scenario to me. If cannot inherit use composition. Or create wrapper class that composes both. BUT: it would be nice to know if there is some requirement for return data, like `Entity3` having `value1` and `value2`?

Comment: Entity1 has 1-m relationship with Entity2

Comment: Please put that stuff into questions code, add the possible annotations and so on.

Comment: What is the problem? If you have an `Entity2` you already have the reference to `Entity1`. What do you mean by "combine"?

Comment: If I call entity2repo.findAll() it will return entity2 object only from the db. I will have an api that will be looking for a mixture of values from entity1 and entity2 and returns it as a combo object to the caller

Answer (score 0):

For me you should use a Facade or a Business Delegator, that should return the object like a Adaptor of the two.

Answer (score 0):

Entity2 already has Entity1, so it's sufficient to return an instance on entity2.
If you want to simplify your API, you should make a new model that combines properties of both and do the mapping behind the scenes.

Comment: If I return an instance of Entity2 how do I access the column value2?

Comment: entity2.getEntity1().getValue2();